# Changing sales stage on Opportunity is not reflected in charts and views - CRM Online 9.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Our CRM was updated to 9.0 and since then we have been experiencing issues when the sales stage on Opportunity (Propose -> Qualify ->Develop -> Close) is changed. The change is not reflected in the system View or the charts. For example, if the Opportunity is changed from Propose to Qualify, in the chart and view it still shows up as Propose. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the Sales Stage business process flow and published it. That solved the issue for me.